# Spring Boot and RabbitMQ exception logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, logback, slf4j

I have a Spring Boot application (latest version) that receives a message in a controller, enqueues it in a RabbitMQ (also latest version) and then process it asynchronously.

Sometimes the message processing fails and an exception is thrown. This exception is logged in WARN level.

How can I set up the log level for all exceptions (or an specific exception) to ERROR level? I'm using SL4J interface and Logback implementation.

Please note that Spring Boot approaches to exception handling only work on controller level and this exceptions are thrown in an asynchronous way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the exception logged?. Are these exceptions coming out of which java package?. One way I can think of adding ErrorHandler to `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` and log messages with ERROR level?. I can only provide some sample based on what exception logs you are seeing at WARN level.